# W8.1 Phone System.Xml.XmlException & System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8.1, xmlreader

My program crashes and gives the following errors while trying to compute these line;

```
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore;

XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(url, settings);
SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
reader.Close();
```

On this line it breaks: XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(url, settings);

Thank you for your help,

Comment: post the stack trace

Comment: > project.DLL!project.App.RootFrame_NavigationFailed(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationFailedEventArgs e) Line 96 C# @AkshaySoam

Comment: For TargetInvocationException plz see the inner exception - it is where the actual problem exists..